# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in Polymer 3.0

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, polymer-3.x

I am new to the Polymer 3.0 library, I am trying to implement ArcGIS in Polymer 3.0.

```html
<!-- This Part Belongs to the HTML Template -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/themes/light/main.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>          
<div id="viewDiv"></div>
```

```js
// Here I defined the module of GIS
require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/MapView"
], function(Map, MapView) {

  var map = new Map({
    basemap: "topo-vector"
  });

  var view = new MapView({
    container: "viewDiv",
    map: map,
    center: [-118.71511, 34.09042],
    zoom: 11
  });
});
```

I used `require` field inside ready function and also outside the function but it doesn't work.
Can anyone please review this and provide me the solution/guideline to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly two ways to integrate ArcGIS API for JavaScript into other frameworks, using **Webpack** or **esri-loader** (ArcGIS JS Guide - Using Frameworks).

I will go directly with, is the most versatile way to achieve it. There are several examples on how use the API with many popular frameworks/libraries through [esri-loader](https://github.com/Esri/esri-loader). Though no polymer3 example, it should not be too difficult to do it taking as example the others.